# How to specify formula for the entire column in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible to specify formula for the entire column?

For example:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `=A1 * 2` |
| 2 | `=A2 * 2` |

After I insert a new line between line 1 and line 2, the B2 cell will be empty.

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `=A1 * 2` |
| 3 |  |
| 2 | `=A2 * 2` |

If it is possible to auto populate B2 cell with `A2 * 2`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done.

On cell b1, use the following formula:

`=ArrayFormula(A1:A*2)`

It can become more complex, or even impossible, depending on which functions you want to use, though.

Answer (score 0):

### Skip Empty Cells

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   IF(LEN(A:A), A:A*2, IFNA(#N/A)))
```

- Returns a blank value if a cell in A:A is blank.

### Skip Text Values

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(
   IF(LEN(A:A), A:A*2, 1/0)))
```

- Returns a blank value if a cell in A:A is blank
- Returns a blank value if a cell in A:A contains text.

  - `"bob"*2=#VALUE!`
  - `IFERROR("bob"*2)=` 
    *(empty value)*